# How to programatically delete a group in django

Tags: django

I created a group in django using

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

g1 = Group.objects.create(name='Name of the group')
```

now I need syntax to delete the group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove a group with a [**`.delete()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#delete):

```
Group.objects.filter(name='Name of the group').delete()
```

Note that if there are `ForeignKey`s to a `Group`, that might trigger a *cascade* of extra removals.

The method will return a dictionary that maps the types to the number of objects that have been removed.

---

If you have a reference to a `Group` object (here `g1`), you can remove it with [**`.delete()`** on the model object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete):

```
g1.delete()
```